# What measures do the police take to control villains with all sorts of quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

After All For One pretty much blew up an entire district in his battle against All Might, one may question the police's ability to imprison him (he is alive and in some sort of iron maiden). On that note, there are probably other notoriously powerful villains with quirks that would make it easy for them to escape from prison.

What measures do the police take to control villains with all sorts of quirks? Perhaps the iron maidens are capable of disabling them?

Another example is when they find Nomu. They just put some handcuffs on him. Hell, the only reason Nomu didn't escape is because it was in a docile state.

Answer (score 0):

These villains were weakened badly and I'm pretty sure All For One was knocked out. They use highly cautious containment procedures. Nomu is controllable by Shigaraki so with Shigaraki not there, Nomu is useless without orders. All For One was weakened and he decided to let himself be taken away because he gave up. If I had to guess what would have happened to Overhaul if he still had arms is that they would use something where he can't touch anything and he would be fed by someone.

Comment: I don't think the Nomu are only controllable by Shigaraki. They seem to be controlled by Kyudai.